# How to make a selection from one table for the same columns?

Tags: laravel

Good afternoon, I would like to receive an answer to the question of how to do it, or links to the article, if any, are at hand

There is a table with parameters

id code value itemID
1 vodakanal yes 1
2 vodakanal no 2
3 vodakanal yes 3
4 test yes2 1

How to get unique itemID from the table for which

```
$result->where([
     ['code', '=', 'vodakanal'],
     ['value', '=', 'yes'],
 ]);
```

And at the same time

```
$result->where(function($query) {
     $query->where('code', 'test')
         ->where('value', 'yes');
 });
```

How to build a query correctly?
the number of different rows in the table can be many later. It is necessary that would look for a unique item on lines with the known code -> value

Comment: Perhaps look at [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#query-scopes) ?

Comment: I think that this problem cannot be solved. (Or I don't understand how to apply)

Comment: did you try my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understand you question correctly. You might want to try this to get unique item ids:

```php
return $result->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('code', 'vodakanal')
        ->where('value', 'yes');
})
->orWhere(function ($query) {
    $query->where('code', 'test')
         ->where('value', 'yes');
})
->get()
->pluck('itemID')
->unique();
```

Comment: ->orWhere (need strict verification  AND)

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro, Maybe that is what you want

```
$result = DB('your table');

$result = $result->where([
     ['code', '=', 'vodakanal'],
     ['value', '=', 'yes'],
 ]);


$result = $result->groupBy('itemId')->havingRaw('COUNT(id) = ', 1)->get()->toArray();
```

By the way where are you from Russia or not

Comment: There are no basic "where" conditions where they should be logically linked "AND"

Comment: you can use any where condition I just write basic query which can take all unique itemId

Comment: need 2 conditions "Where"  different values "code" and "values"

$result->where([
     ['code', '=', 'vodakanal'],
     ['value', '=', 'yes'],
 ]);

+

$result->where(function($query) {
     $query->where('code', 'test')
         ->where('value', 'yes');
 });

= error  (but logic need AND)

Comment: can you write your expected output

Comment: i need to get  itemID = 1.

when i use filter   ($result->where([
     ['code', '=', 'vodakanal'],
     ['value', '=', 'yes'],
 ]);)  +

($result->where([
     ['code', '=', 'test '],
     ['value', '=', 'yes2'],
 ]);)

Comment: you can not use and operator for your expected result

Comment: i need to use and operator.